# Use module with and without routes configured

Tags: angular

I want to reuse my module for two different cases. One case I need the Routes specified and in another I don't need the routes.

I have the following module

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MyComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES),
        RouterModule
    ],

    declarations: [
        MyComponent
    ],
    exports: [MyComponent],
    providers: []
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

I tried creating another module with another name and without the routes set but it doesn't matter it will only configure it to the module that's loaded first.

Is it possible to use the same module configured with and without Routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need create SharedModule without Routes that declares and exports shareable components + create WithRoutesModule module with routes that just import this SharedModule.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [something]
})
export class WithRoutesModule {
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    somethingd
],    
declarations: [
  SharedComponent
],
  exports: [SharedComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

Comment: I was skeptical of whether this would work before I saw this answer . Solved my doubts